# VirtualPathProvider Not Working on Hosting Environment

Tags: iis-7, precompiled, virtualpathprovider

My .Net project works fine on Local IIS7 (Windows 7 IIS7 x86). But it does not work on hosting environment (W2008 Server x64 IIS7). I can fully control hosting environment. But I could not locate the error. When working locally I can access the USer Controls in the DLL via VirtualPathProvider, but i receive error

> The file '/TarimWeb/TarisApp/TarisUI/CariBanka.ascx' does not exist.

on hositng environment.

I can provide any information, but i do not know what my helper would need to know.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you registered the provider in Global.asax on your hosted environment? Is the hosted running in medium trust?

Comment: Yes. Both are correct. Found the solution later on. But those are important points that should be settled.

Answer (score 4):

So, I totally forgot that "PreCompiled Web Sites" cannot use VirtualPathProviders.

I found a work around @ http://sunali.com/2008/01/09/virtualpathprovider-in-precompiled-web-sites/

It DID work for me too...